# Global route in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Some context: I've setup my Laravel 5 app to be split into modules. The boot() function in my AppServiceProvider looks like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    // We want to register the modules in the Modules folder
    $modulesPath = app_path() . '/Modules';
    $handle      = opendir($modulesPath);

    // Loop through the module directory and register each module
    while (($module = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($module != "." && $module != ".." && is_dir("{$modulesPath}/{$module}")) {
            // Check if there are routes for that module, if so include
            if (file_exists($modulesPath . '/' . $module . '/routes.php')) {
                include $modulesPath . '/' . $module . '/routes.php';
            }

            // Check if there are views for that module, if so set a namespace for those views
            if (is_dir($modulesPath . '/' . $module . '/Views')) {
                $this->loadViewsFrom($modulesPath . '/' . $module . '/Views', strtolower($module));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to be able to keep things separated in modules, but also have global routes and a global controller. Therefore, each module has its own routes.php file that looks something like this:

```
<?php

Route::group(array('module'=>'MyModule','namespace' => 'NexusHub\Modules\MyModule\Controllers'), function() {
    Route::resource('mymodule', 'MyModuleController');
});
```

I then have a global routes.php file that looks like this:

```
<?php

Route::any('{catchall}', 'GlobalController@myAction')->where('catchall', '(.*)');

Route::group(array('module'=>'Global'), function() {
    Route::resource('', 'GlobalController');
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that it seems my catchall route isn't picking up for the modules. The modules run their own routes but the catchall route is ignored.

As far as why I'm trying to accomplish this, for now the purpose is that all modules use the same layout, and that layout requires some data to be retrieved always, so the global controller would grab what's needed and make it available to the layout. But I suppose there may be some other things in the future where having a global route file that can catch multiple different routes based on arbitrary rules and run additional code would come in handy.

**UPDATE:** Removed the line that included the global routes since I realized they already got included by default anyway.

Comment: have you tried including your global routes after you include your module routes?

Comment: Just tried, didn't matter. I also realized, I don't even need that line, the global route file gets loaded no matter, the include app_path() . '/Http/routes.php'; line is actually not needed. And if I remove it, the global routes still get included after the module ones.

Comment: From your description, if you’re just trying to inject some data to _all_ routes/views, then it sounds like view composers are a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Will look into view composers. I saw the basic description in Laravel docs, but not sure where I would declare those and how to use them for a layout. I was able to get things working using MiddleWare, but not really sure this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing what I wanted using middleware instead (see https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#global-middleware).

In my case I used something similar to the BeforeMiddleware class example and registered it in the $middleware property of my app/Http/Kernel.php class since it's global and not route dependant.

Comment: Could you summarize your solution ?

Comment: Good point, I've updated the answer to point people in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your global routes file is being loaded first.

Try moving your service provider that loads all your module routes before the "App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider" in the config/app.php file.

...see if that helps.

Comment: See my comments on your comment above, I tried moving it and it didn't fix the problem. I also removed the loading of the global routes from the boot() function as I realized the global routes were being loaded anyway, and the file gets included after the module files.

Comment: MMmm... try declaring your catch all route in an App::before application filter.

Comment: Can' say I really know what you mean by App::before filter. But the impression I'm getting is that what I'm trying to do won't work with routes. Looking at the functions in the Router class, seems like you only ever get one route that gets matched. If true, then I might just need to come up with a different approach.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do it as long as you have the catch all being registered last. I wish "php artisan route:list" listed the routes in registered order. One thing I would try is moving the global routes into a service provider and make sure its last in the 'providers' array.